# Inverse of the lognormal distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I need to find the inverse of a given lognormal distribution.
Since there is no inbuilt function in R for inverse lognormal, I need to design my own.

I have this lognormal distribution for a random variable 'x'

```
 f_lambda <- function(x,mu,sig) {dlnorm(x, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sig,log=FALSE)}
```

On wikipedia it says

```
 G(y) = 1- F(1/y)
```

where G(Y)n is the inverse distribution to F(X) and X= 1/Y.

But, I am confused as to how to encode F(1/y) in r and what to use to define that distribution - mu or 1/mu.

I have estimates of mu and sigma for F(x).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From [an old bulletin board](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-January/017625.html): "Inverse cdfs are also called quantile functions, and in R they are named
qxxxx; cdfs are pxxxx, random numbers are rxxxx, density is dxxxx, where
xxxx names the distribution family. Eg qnorm, pnorm, rnorm, dnorm". So `qlnorm` should probably do the job.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the quantile distribution is the inverse of a cumulative distribution. This really means:

[image: F(x) = p]

[image: x = F^-1(p)]

which means that to find the inverse of the lognormal distribution you can use

```
qlnorm()
```