# How to generate random values from "inverse log-normal distribution" in R

Tags: r, random, simulation

I am trying to replicate one part of the simulating programming results in a working paper, which says the authors '**generate random values from the right-skewed "inverse log-normal" distribution with an expected median value of w_median = 0.85, with an additional condition, 0 <= w <= 1,**' which obviously means random values are within 0 and 1. I am using R, and there are functions for generating "log-normal" distributions like dlnorm, plnorm, qlnorm, rlnorm, and it's quite obvious to generate random values from log-normal distributions with those functions like:

```
rand_val <- rlnorm(1000, meanlog=log(0.85))
hist(rand_val, breaks=100)

median(rand_val) # 0.8856299
min(rand_val) # 0.04660691
max(rand_val) # 23.33998
```

But I have no idea about how to generate the random values from "**inverse log-normal**" distribution. There was essentially the same question raised before ([Inverse of the lognormal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525601/inverse-of-the-lognormal-distribution)), and they suggested using qlnorm function, but I am not sure how that function works for generating random values from inverse log-normal distribution, especially **with additional conditions of mine as mentioned: 1) expected median value = 0.85; 2) random values are within 0 to 1.** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did the paper give any statistics for the standard deviation?. You can get a distribution which has an upper limit of 1.0 if you reduce the sdlog e.g. `rand_val <- rlnorm(1000, meanlog=log(0.85), sdlog = 0.05)`

Comment: No. No information for standard deviation and mean of "inverse log-normal" distribution. And as I mentioned above, I am trying to generate random values from "inverse" log-normal, not just log-normal distribution! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if by "inverse lognormal" they mean that `1/w` has a lognormal distribution.  In which case this will roughly do it, although the sd might be larger with a cut-off at `w=1`: `rand_val <- 1/rlnorm(1000, meanlog=-log(0.85),sdlog = 0.06)`